# tabs menu after login in Ionic3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I want to redirect users to tabsmenu page after login on the app.

But user click the login button, the app shows only homepage in first access to app.

[image]

After refreshing the app tabsmenu looks.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {App, NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {TabsPage} from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import {Login} from '../pages/login/login';

import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    // Initialize Firebase
    let config = {
      apiKey: "##",
      authDomain: "#.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "#.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "#",
      storageBucket: "#.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "##"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

        if (!user) {
          console.log("not login");
          this.rootPage = Login;

        } else {
          console.log("login");
          this.rootPage = TabsPage;
        }

      }
    );

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear for me.Can you provide more info about your use case?

Comment: I have a login page and users input email&password. Then click the login button. If user login successfully app rotates to tabsmenu as the following images it shows only selected tab menu 'Home' not like second image. After refresh or reopen the app it shows tabs menu with selected tab 'Home'. @Sampath

Comment: In your login success function, you set rootpage = HomePage, do you?

Comment: Yes, that's right but it was the wrong way. I added solution. @Duannx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. That was a fault on loginUser function. I wrote this.nav.setRoot(HomePage) because of that it rotates to homepage on first login. Thanks for responses!

```
loginUser(): void {
        if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
            console.log(this.loginForm.value);
        } else {
            this.authData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password).then(authData => {
                this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
                    this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);
                });
            }, error => {
                this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        message: error.message,
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                text: "Ok",
                                role: 'cancel'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                    alert.present();
                });
            });

            this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
            this.loading.present();
        }
    }
```